# Alien program rebus

Tags: rebus, movies

Given the following `Java` program:

```
public class Alien {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        home();
    }
}
```

What classic movie quote is this referencing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is it:

> E.T.

Because:

> E.T. Phone (calling) home.

Comment: Haha. Someone was watching this. ^vote 5 secs after posting.

Comment: that was fast, very fast ;D *your avatar*

Comment: Yah. That's actually a painting I did on a 14"x14" canvas. @ABcDexter. One of a kind.  Fits this question quite well I suppose.

Comment: Actually was writing the same thing, you did it first. Kudos :-)

Comment: I was about to ask where "Phone" comes from, all I see is Alien class  calling home...oh wait.. +1 fast answer

Comment: Clarified that it's "calling" home()